# Crossover.com not opening on my laptop but working on another laptop

Tags: internet, ssl, website

i am trying to open crossover.com website on my personal laptop but it says `err_connection_refused`. But when i open the same website on my office laptop it works fine. I am able to login and play with website. And yes for both the laptops i use the same WiFi network at home.
Moreover the website is opening on my Cellphone Chrome browser as well.

I have disabled firewall and checked internet settings as well. Could anyone please suggest me what can be wrong here. ?

Comment: Is this problem specific to a single site or do you fail to access lots of sites or even all sites?

Comment: sometimes stackoverflow.com and superuser.com also not opening on my laptop. This is the same case with my housemate...he is also able to access same websites on his office laptop...but on our personal laptops we are unable to open it....what can make a difference here

Comment: I would suggest that it is either malicious software (virus, trojans...), some security software (antivirus, parental control...) or simply an unstable system. It's not really possible to say more from the few details.

Comment: Okay there are software i.e. antivirus, firewall are on my laptop, but on my friend's laptop it has a fresh installation...still its not working on his machine ? that is a strange reason too ?

Comment: I have no idea what the fresh installation involves, but often it involves antivirus too or it might even involve some unwanted software like [SuperFish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superfish)  which messes with your connection.

Comment: Its a windows 10 evaluation copy nothing else